# How do I use Data.Concurrent.mergeIO?

Tags: multithreading, haskell, concurrency

I see two functions mergeio and nmergeio in Data.Concurrent, but I can't find any examples of how they work.

Has anyone worked with these before?  My hope is that I can use these to get a function like "parMapM".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import Control.Concurrent (mergeIO, nmergeIO)

main = do
  xs <- mergeIO (map (*2) [1..10])
                (map (+3) [100..110])
  print xs

  xs <- nmergeIO [ map (\x->x*x) [1..10]
                 , map (\x->x+x) [1..10]
                 ]
  print $ maximum xs
```

Output:

```
[2,4,103,6,104,8,105,10,106,12,107,14,108,16,109,18,110,20,111,112,113]
100
```

The internal order may differ depending on how quickly each thread pitches back results.

Writing `parMapM` is a little tricky, but the result is nice:

```
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Concurrent.STM
import Control.Exception
import Control.Monad
import Data.Word
import System.IO

import qualified Data.ByteString as BS

main :: IO ()
main = do
  xs <- parMapM (reverse . show) $ replicate 4 (readFromNet 5)
  print xs
```

We'll read from `/dev/urandom` as a standin:

```
readFromNet :: Int -> IO [Word8]
readFromNet n = do
  h <- openFile "/dev/urandom" ReadMode 
  let go :: Int -> IO [Word8]
      go 0 = return []
      go remaining = do s <- BS.head <$> BS.hGet h 1
                        ss <- go (remaining-1)
                        return (s:ss)
  go n
```

Finally the gory bits:

```
parMapM :: (a -> b) -> [IO [a]] -> IO [b]
parMapM f as = do
  kids <- newMVar []
  answers <- atomically $ newTVar []
  forM_ as $ \ a ->
    do mvar <- newEmptyMVar
       curkids <- takeMVar kids
       putMVar kids (mvar:curkids)
       let ax = do xs <- a
                   atomically $ do sofar <- readTVar answers
                                   writeTVar answers (sofar ++ xs)
       forkIO (ax `finally` putMVar mvar ())
  waitForChildren kids
  atomically $ map f <$> readTVar answers
  where
    waitForChildren kids = do ks <- takeMVar kids
                              case ks of
                                [] -> return ()
                                m:ms -> do
                                  putMVar kids ms
                                  takeMVar m
                                  waitForChildren kids
```

It works by having the children write their answers to a `TVar` while the main thread waits for the children to signal their completion.

Unfortunately, the results are "chunky" because `readFromNet` is unaware of communication issues, so we get all values from a given thread at once. If you don't mind making them get their hands dirty, you could do so as in the following:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  let threads = 3
      nbytes  = 10
      total   = nbytes * threads
  byte <- newEmptyMVar
  let thr = forkIO $ readFromNetwork nbytes byte
      go 0 = return []
      go n = do b <- takeMVar byte
                bs <- go (n-1)
                return (b:bs)
  sequence_ $ replicate threads thr
  values <- map (reverse . show) <$> go total
  print values
```

Then the worker looks like

```
readFromNetwork :: Int -> MVar Word8 -> IO ()
readFromNetwork n var = do
  -- or something...
  h <- openFile "/dev/urandom" ReadMode 
  let go 0 = return ()
      go remaining = do s <- BS.hGet h 1
                        putMVar var (BS.head s)
                        go (remaining-1)
  go n
```

Comment: Thanks!  So I guess it doesn't work with IO actions, e.g.

    mergeIO (map getFromNetwork [...])

Comment: @Bill Both mergeIO and nmergeIO take pure lists — [a] rather than IO [a] — so trying to use an action such as getFromNetwork won't typecheck.